# Is it possible to remove file upload size limit in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I know how to restrict file size for uploads in Nginx configuration and I know how to decrease it or increase it.

But in this case (which is a VOD application for internal usage) I need to remove it altogether.

I didn't find anything online. Is it possible, and how?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `client_max_body_size 0` will disable size checking.